# Create a map with a generic type

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create a map that will map string values to functions. Here's the interface I created (as in Java 8 but I can't use it):

```
interface Function<T, U> {
    U apply(T t);
}
```

Now, I created a sort method to sort my pojo based on some attributes:

```
public <U extends Comparable<U>> void sortPojoBy(Function<Pojo, U> f) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Book> () {
            @Override
            public int compare(Pojo first, Pojo second) {
                return f.apply(first).compareTo(f.apply(second));
            }
        });
}
```

Then I can call it passing an anonymous class of a function to sort by the attribute I want, ex:

```
sortBooksBy(new Function<Pojo, Double>(){
                @Override
                public Double apply(Pojo p) {
                    return p.getPrice();
                }
            });
```

Now I'm having troubles to create the map. Ideally I would like something like this:

```
Map<String, Function<Pojo, T extends Comparable<T>>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I know that I cannot do something like this, my current workaround is to create a map with a raw Function.

```
private Map<String, Function> map = new HashMap<>();
    {
        map.put("price", new Function<Pojo, Double>(){
            @Override
            public Double apply(Pojo t) {
                return t.getPrice();
            }           
        });
        map.put("name", new Function<Pojo, String>(){
            @Override
            public String apply(Pojo t) {
                return t.getTitle();
            }

        });
    }
```

I need a map because I get the attribute values (name, price, etc.) from a JSON config file.

So my question is, is there any way to create my map to ensure that the type T of the function is comparable to itself? (I can deal with the workaround for now, as I'll fill it manually)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to change it so that all Functions are sure to return a usable Comparable in the first place. In other words, move the argument you have in the Map to a parameter of Function.

```
interface Function<T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> {
    U apply(T t);
}
```

Your Map declaration is now just

```
Map<String, Function<Pojo, ?>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Your generic method `sortPojoBy` now also performs a wildcard capture of `U`.

```
public <U extends Comparable<? super U>> void sortPojoBy(Function<Pojo, U> f);
```

As a side note, I changed your Comparable declaration slightly. `T extends Comparable<? super T>` is the typical form. This is in case `T` is a subclass of the argument it has provided to `Comparable`.